# Story about a boy who can put a plant in his mouth to turn himself into a bird temporarily, but it becomes permanent if he swallows it

Tags: story-identification

I am searching for a story about a boy who can, by putting a plant in his mouth, turn into a bird temporarily. However, the change becomes permanent if he swallows the plant. It might have been an audio book, but I just don't remember more, and I don't remember when I first read or heard it. I tried to find it myself by checking many different Google questions and sites for audio books, etc., but I failed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  If you recall any more details, please [edit] them into your question.  When was it that you heard this?